# How to tell the XCode debugger to only stop at breakpoints? (and not at exceptions)

Tags: c++, c, xcode, macos

I'm writing a 3rd party plug-in for a closed-source application. I'm running into a problem with the XCode debugger.

I'd like to use the debugger to step through the code of the plug-in I'm writing. To do this, I've set a breakpoint in my code, I've launched the host app, and then I've attached the XCode debugger to the host app's process. My problem is that, rather than stopping at my breakpoint, the debugger stops instead at an exception thrown by another part of the program. (Specifically, this: `Thread 2: EXC_ARITHMETIC (code=EXC_i386_DIV, subcode=0x0)`)

This exception is thrown so often that it effectively makes it impossible to step through the code I'm actually interested in.

I can't catch and handle this exception, because I don't have the source code for the part of the app that throws it.

In this situation, can anyone suggest how I might be able to debug my code? Is there any way to tell the XCode debugger to simply "ignore" this particular `EXC_ARITHMETIC` exception, and, instead, to stop only on the breakpoints that I've explicitly set?

*UPDATE*

@user1118321 suggested turning off exception breakpoints using the breakpoints pane. I've tried to do so using the settings shown here.

[image]

I thought that selecting "Automatically continue after evaluating" might keep the debugger from stopping. It didn't.

I also tried issuing `cont` to the debugger after stopping. This doesn't seem to work either.

[image]

Can anyone you advise me on what settings I should enter here to keep the debugger from stopping on my `EXC_ARITHMETIC` exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed the links suggested by @user1118321. After several hours of head scratching, I couldn't figure out how to either turn off or handle the integer division by zero exception.  If anyone has any ideas I'd be happy to hear them.

I did find a workaround, though, which is to use GDB instead of XCode. Unlike XCode, GDB doesn't seem to stop on the `EXC_ARITHMETIC` and lets me step into my code. So, for the time being I'm going to switch over to GDB for debugging.

*EDIT*

A second (better) workaround, in my case, involved suspending the thread that was throwing the exception. This also allowed me to step through my plugin's code.

Answer (score 3):

That's an integer "division by zero" error exception. They aren't propagated as C++ exceptions as far as I'm aware, which is why you can't not break on them.

Does that happen even if your plugin isn't loaded? If it doesn't, your plugin is causing a division by zero somehow.

Comment: Yeah, this happens even when my plugin isn't loaded. So I don't think my plugin has much to do with it. :(

Comment: Ah, yeah. THat's right. It's a hardware exception. Depending on when your plug-in loads, you may be able to turn the hardware exception off with the appropriate assembly. (I ran into this exact issue writing plug-ins for Cubase or Nuendo, if I recall.) You might even be able to get the debugger to turn it off for you before running the app. I think [this link](http://www.osdever.net/tutorials/view/interrupts-exceptions-and-idts-part-2-exceptions) describes how to write your own exception handler for them. You could probably install one that simply ignores the exception and continues.

Comment: @dB' [This link](http://www.digitalmars.com/d/archives/c++/Traping_divide_by_zero_5728.html) also talks about the ability to turn off the exception altogether. Might be worth a look.

Comment: Thx! I'll check these out.